# Plotting graph on top of World map

Tags: python, graph, geolocation, geoip

I'm trying to plot a graph representing a P2P network on top of a world map. I want to be able to draw vertices and edges, and it has to work with several thousands of veritces/edges on a map.

Is there a python library that allows me to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) package with the [basemap toolkit](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/basemap/doc/html/api/basemap_api.html) might work for you. See [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Maps) for some examples of its use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the canvas object in the tkinter library for basic drawing.
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm